# pyarmor: unable to build using build_meta

Tags: python, macos, pyarmor

I am trying to  use build-pyarmored-wheel to build a company project, I am following steps as described in   https://pyarmor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build-wheel.html?highlight=pyproject.toml#build-pyarmored-wheel

content of
pyproject.toml

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools", "wheel"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

produces
Building wheels for collected packages: company-project
  Building wheel for company-project (pyproject.toml) ... done
  Created wheel for company-project: filename=company_project-1.0.0.0-py3-none-any.whl size=3906 sha256=dd639eb8fe24db685bb9b73576b7cdca656356211c935e031e08314b9d2ef562
```

when I change the content of pyproject.toml

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools", "wheel", "pyarmor>7.2.0"]
build-backend = "pyarmor.build_meta"
```

error is generated is

```
  Building wheel for company-project (pyproject.toml) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Users/employee/.pyenv/versions/3.6.7/bin/python /Users/employee/.pyenv/versions/3.6.7/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py build_wheel /var/folders/cd/ztpbtx9x13x634f270x96mbxjqz_sg/T/tmp2mqap73h
       cwd: /Users/employee/DEV/company-project
  Complete output (12 lines):
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/employee/.pyenv/versions/3.6.7/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
      main()
    File "/Users/employee/.pyenv/versions/3.6.7/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 345, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "/Users/employee/.pyenv/versions/3.6.7/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 262, in build_wheel
      metadata_directory)
    File "/private/var/folders/cd/ztpbtx9x13x634f270x96mbxjqz_sg/T/pip-build-env-euh9w736/overlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyarmor/build_meta.py", line 100, in build_wheel
      config_settings = _fix_config(config_settings, obf_options)
    File "/private/var/folders/cd/ztpbtx9x13x634f270x96mbxjqz_sg/T/pip-build-env-euh9w736/overlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyarmor/build_meta.py", line 72, in _fix_config
      from pip._internal.configuration import Configuration, ConfigurationError
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for company-project
Failed to build company-project
ERROR: Failed to build one or more wheels
```

If it helps setup.py looks like as follows

```
from os import path
import re
from setuptools import find_packages, setup


def open_file(filepath, mode='r'):
    here = path.abspath(path.dirname(__file__))
    full_path = path.join(here, filepath)
    return open(full_path, mode)


def find_version(package):
    with open_file('{}/__init__.py'.format(package)) as f:
        return re.findall(r"^__version__ = '([^']+)'\r?$", f.read(), re.M)[0]


def find_requires():
    with open_file('requirements.txt') as f:
        return [line.strip() for line in f]


NAME = 'company-project'
VERSION = find_version('company_project’)
PACKAGES = find_packages()
REQUIRES = find_requires()

setup(
    name=NAME,
    version=VERSION,
    packages=PACKAGES,
    include_package_data=True,
    zip_safe=False,
    install_requires=REQUIRES
)
```

Comment: Having the same issue, did you ever figure it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method described in the linked guide is marked as not supported at the bottom of the page

> Build pyarmored wheel is a helper function, there is no more support for this.

This is further confirmed on the github issues (like [here](https://github.com/dashingsoft/pyarmor/issues/698#issuecomment-1039030406))

> Please check the documentation about wheel, there is no support for this feature.

---

What worked for me is to simply obfuscate the code first and generate the package from the obfuscated code

Make sure to include the `pytransform` library in the package using `package_data` with setuptools.